# Healthkit sync with Strava

Tags: ios, health-kit

I am using iOS 8.1 with Healthkit and Strava version 4.2.2 with sync enabled in strava to push cycling data to Healthkit.

My cycle data is logged with Garmin which uses garmin connect to sync to the Garmin cloud, and the data is then pushed to Strava cloud and from there can be viewed on the Strava app on iOS.

How is the data meant to go from Strava app to healthkit?

Is it possible to use strava and healthkit in this fashion?

Note at this point in time garmin connect does not support pushing data to healthkit.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible to link Strava and HealthKit. Load up your Strava app then go to:

1. More
2. Settings
3. Link other services
4. Health should be listed as an option to connect to

Official Strava link: https://strava.zendesk.com/entries/55624974-Changes-in-Strava-version-4-2-1-for-iOS#health

Comment: I have already performed the above but not data is pushed from strava to healthkit ... the healthkit cupboard is bare yet strava continues to pull in cycles from garmin connect

Comment: "Strava will also send data to Heath such as activity type, distance, time, and calories. These details will be sent to Health only when the data is downloaded from the server. For type/distance/time, this happens just by scrolling through the feed. If you want to get historical Strava activity data into Health, you would need to scroll back through your 'Me' feed in the app. If you want Health to have the calories from a given activity, you’ll need to actually tap into the activity."   so the web link agrees with what you are saying but something is amiss

Comment: Might be worth raising a support ticket with strava

Comment: Is Strava listed in your HealthKit sources? If it is check to see that the options are all set to allow Strava to write data, if not then try removing and re-adding Strava to HealthKit

Comment: already listed - will try re-adding!  I had already tried deleting strava and reinstalling once